# Vaciar un elemento de localstorage

Tags: javascript, checkbox

Tengo un arreglo de columnas con checkboxes los cuales guardan si están seleccionados o no en localstorage, al ingresar a esa vista todos los checkboxes aparecen seleccionados por default. Quiero implementar un botón que deseleccione todos los checkboxes, se vacie el elemento del localstorage y se vayan guardando nuevamente conforme se vayan seleccionando

Comment: `localstorage.setItem("item","")`, solo lo vinculas con el evento de un boton

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes 2 opciones en este caso, una es usando el:

```
localStorage.setItem("nombreStorage", ""); //Para guardarlo a vacío.
```

Y la otra es:

```
localStorage.removeItem("nombreStorage"); 

//No recomiendo usarla en este escenario ya que te hará hacer más comprobaciones como la del localStorage.getItem("nombreStorage"); Te devolverá null.
```

E ir añadiendo los elementos de nuevo, no especificas la estructura que tienes, pero así debería servirte.

Te voy a poner un ejemplo para que tengas la base clara:

```
//Supongamos que tengo elementos en el localStorage y los quiero eliminar para volver a ingresar elementos.

localStorage.setItem("nombreStorage", ""); //Con esto el valor sería "" osea vacío.

//Ahora supongamos que quiero ir añadiendo elementos, con un separador -> ", "

let elementos = localStorage.getItem("nombreStorage") != "" ? localStorage.getItem("nombreStorage").split(", ") : new Array();

//La variable elementos, tendrá una invocación de un Array en caso de ser vacía o será un array de elementos existentes que se han dividido, pero en este caso en concreto será la invocación de un Array().

//Antes de añadir un elemento tenemos que comprobar si realmente existe para evitar la duplicidad de los datos.

//Por poner un ejemplo, me voy a referir a un checkbox con id: check_id

if($('#check_id').attr("value").indexOf(", ") == -1 && elementos.indexOf($('#check_id').attr("value")) != -1){ //Si es diferente a -1 significaría que existe en el Array por lo cual no debemos añadir el mismo elemento, me refiero al uso del método de Array.prototype.indexOf()

   localStorage.setItem("nombreStorage", localStorage.getItem("nombreStorage") + ", "); //Así añadirías el elemento.

}
```

También comentas que tienes un botón, al cual cuando le das se borran los elementos del localStorage y también se dejan de estar activados los checkboxes.

```
//Para ello al dar al botón se activara el evento click para ello, por las etiquetas veo que hablas de javascript, por lo cual tendrás que usar la funcion addEventListener()

let boton = document.getElementById("algunBoton");

boton.addEventListener("click", function(){

    //Hacemos uso de form para poder acceder al form padre.

    
 this.form.querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox']:checked").forEach(function(node) 
 {
    node.checked = false;
 });

 //Por ultimo vaciado del local storage
 
 localStorage.setItem("nombreStorage", "");

}, false);
```

Creo que con esto se puede entender como hacer lo que estas preguntando.